# Is Passenger Deprecated for Nginx versions above 1.14?

Tags: nginx

I updated nginx from version `1.14` to `1.18 (Ubuntu)` on `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Doing so appeared to break passenger.  So I uninstalled and attempted to reinstall the Open Source Passenger version via the [Passenger installation Ubuntu 18.04 instructions](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/bionic/).

I got to this line:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

Which throws this error

> libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (< 1.14.1) but 1.18.0-3ubuntu1+bionic1 is to be installed

**Update** I also attempted with the enterprise version. Following the enterprise version installation instructions, I received a similar error message:

> libnginx-mod-http-passenger-enterprise : Depends: nginx-common (< 1.14.1) but 1.18.0-3ubuntu1+bionic1 is to be installed

I did attempt to research the issue and I found [this issue on Phusion's GitHub](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2122) as well as [this more recent issue](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2349). It appears that what most people are doing is rolling back their nginx version to `1.14`.

Comment: Yes, Passenger is not supported on NGINX anymore, and never has been by NGINX Upstream.  It's a third party module that breaks some things.  This will always be the case.  NGINX 1.14 is also VERY old and has a lot of security holes in it that would need patching to use in production.

Comment: Did you have a chance of upgrading to 20.04 and install nginx 1.18 + Passenger?

Comment: Great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010880/is-passenger-deprecated-for-nginx-versions-above-1-14

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which method you used to install nginx 1.14 + passenger.
At any rate, it does appear that, for Ubuntu 18.04, you cannot get nginx 1.18 + passenger.

So you might try upgrading Ubuntu, or rolling back nginx as you say. Passenger is not recommended for security reasons, but you could still have the version you are referring to, see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1041592/326962).

Note that as stated [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/upgrade/oss/#debian_ubuntu) "In July 2017, the Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty packages for Passenger were changed from a static to a dynamic module package."
Perhaps you can try compiling from source, in a way that the dynamic module is loaded. YMMV.

**Related**:

1. https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2263
2. https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2291

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got says that it's impossible to install `passenger` because it depends on `nginx-common < 1.14.1`.

To fix this, the first thing you have to do is check if your system still knows the previous version of Nginx:

```bsh
apt show nginx -a | egrep "^(Package|Version|APT-Sources|$)"
```

The output will be something similar to this:

```
Package: nginx
Version: 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.9
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages

Package: nginx
Version: 1.14.0-0ubuntu1
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

And you will probably have version `1.18-<somethin>`. To avoid version `1.18` to be installed, you have two options:

1. Remove the repository you've added to be able to update `nginx`.  Either using `sudo apt-add-repository --remove <repository>` or going through sources at `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and commenting out or removing the said repository.
2. Blocking `nginx` to upgrade to versions different from `1.14`:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install nginx=1.14.0-0ubuntu1 nginx-common=1.14.0-0ubuntu1
sudo apt-mark hold nginx nginx-common
```

After that, you shall be able to reinstall `libnginx-mod-http-passenger`.